# MYSQL: Display data using mathematical method and group by date

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, which are **qrc_factory_bay** and **qrc_loading_bay_tracking**. Table **qrc_factory_bay** is stored how many bays (in the bay and outside the bay) are in a factory. Table **qrc_loading_bay_tracking** is to record the bay that is used daily. Below is the query that i used:

```
SELECT qrc_loading_bay_tracking.date_in, 
    COUNT(qrc_loading_bay_tracking.id) AS total_bay_used, 
    FLOOR(SUM(qrc_factory_bay.in_bay + qrc_factory_bay.out_bay)) AS total_loading_bay 
FROM qrc_factory_bay 
INNER JOIN qrc_loading_bay_tracking ON qrc_loading_bay_tracking.factory_bay_id = qrc_factory_bay.id 
WHERE qrc_loading_bay_tracking.date_in >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY ) 
    AND qrc_factory_bay.status = 1 
GROUP BY qrc_loading_bay_tracking.date_in
```

The results as shown below:

[image]

The highlighted value is wrong. The supposed should be 78. 78 is the total loading bay counted at table **qrc_factory_bay**. Thus, can I know what is the problem? Can anyone fix the query?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to post the input data.

Comment: You highlighted two values. Which one is wrong?

Comment: @Barmar both. both data should be 78